# Failed to delete a custom domain in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have tried to use multiple methods for domain deletion.
But the exceptions thrown leave me clueless.

This is the domain information under Microsoft Graph PowerShell.

```
Get-MgDomain

Id                                AuthenticationType AvailabilityStatus IsAdminManaged IsDefault IsInitial IsRoot IsVerified Manufacturer Model PasswordNotificationWindowInDays PasswordValidityPeriodInDays SupportedServices
--                                ------------------ ------------------ -------------- --------- --------- ------ ---------- ------------ ----- -------------------------------- ---------------------------- -----------------
deathknight0718qq.onmicrosoft.com Managed                               True           False     True      True   True                          14                               2147483647                   {Email, OfficeCommunicationsOnline, MoeraDomain}
foliagecn.onmicrosoft.com         Managed                               True           False     False     True   True                          14                               2147483647                   {Email, OfficeCommunicationsOnline, MoeraDomain}
```

When I run Remove-MgDomain, it throws clueless exceptions.

```
Remove-MgDomain -DomainId foliagecn.onmicrosoft.com
Remove-MgDomain : Domain deletion attempt failed.
所在位置 行:1 字符: 1
+ Remove-MgDomain -DomainId foliagecn.onmicrosoft.com
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: ({ DomainId = fo...m, IfMatch =  }:<>f__AnonymousType132`2) [Remove-MgDomain_Delete1]，RestException`1
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Request_BadRequest,Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Cmdlets.RemoveMgDomain_Delete1
```

Same as Force Delete

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Identity.DirectoryManagement
$params = @{ DisableUserAccounts = $true }
Invoke-MgForceDomainDelete -DomainId foliagecn.onmicrosoft.com -BodyParameter $params
Invoke-MgForceDomainDelete : Domain deletion attempt failed.
所在位置 行:1 字符: 1
+ Invoke-MgForceDomainDelete -DomainId foliagecn.onmicrosoft.com -BodyP ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: ({ DomainId = fo...ionJsonSchema }:<>f__AnonymousType90`2) [Invoke-MgForceDomainDelete_Force1]，RestException`1
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Request_BadRequest,Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Cmdlets.InvokeMgForceDomainDelete_Force1
```

When I go to entra.microsoft.com to remove it, it throws the same exception message.

There is only one user for the entire cloud.

Comment: The domain may be in use. If there are any active users or services associated with the domain, it cannot be deleted. Try to remove any users or services that are no longer needed, and then try to delete the domain again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible causes were found by themselves:

> You can't remove the ".onmicrosoft.com" domain from your account. When you remove a domain, user accounts will revert back to the ".onmicrosoft.com" address as the Primary SMTP/UserprincipalName.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-with-domains/remove-a-domain?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: This is the correct answer, don't forget to accept this answer to make the community more better